# Is it true that organic chemistry as an independent research field is no longer developing?

Tags: organic-chemistry, chemical-biology

One of my professors told me that organic chemistry has become a tool for biological research, rather than an active research field of its own.

Is this assertion valid? Does it describe correctly the general attitude towards organic chemistry in research institutions today?

Comment: Not sure if this actually counts as a valid (Chemistry) question here. Perhaps it's (somewhat) better off on Academia.SE?

Comment: Perhaps it is, but I wanted to hear what the chemists have to say about this.

Comment: Have you considered asking this at [The Table](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table)? O:)

Comment: Bit afraid it is. ...material chemistry is another field which actually benefits of organic chemistry

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what that is (I know it exists, but don't know what it is exactly)...

Comment: Do believe organic chemistry is alive and well. Consider, e.g., https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3979/suggestions-for-synthesis-golf-targets

Comment: @hBy2Py I think it's been fairly well demonstrated that we can synthesise more or less anything given enough time and money. These games are enjoyable intellectually, but I'm not sure they're adding much value any more (sadly). But that doesn't mean organic chemistry is dead. Pure synthesis, I feel, is but there are so many other things that synthesis can be applied to. Just need to get out the bunker a little :)

Comment: How many journals are there now publishing synthetic chemistry papers? Seems like there's a new one every year. Doesn't sound like a subject in decline to me.

Comment: @Waylander A vast amount of rubbish is published. There's very little value added from another total synthesis of strychnine, or yet another way to do an allylic oxidation. I got sick of barrages of claimed yields of 95-100%, which were clearly nonsense. There's some interesting stuff, but not enough to go round. My point is there's loads of interesting applications in supramolecular chemistry, chemical biology etc begging for molecules and I think people who think of themselves as synthetic chemists should embrace that.

Comment: @awjlogan I respectfully disagree. Knowing all the walls you can run against in total synthesis from my own experience it is definitely *not* so that we can synthesise anything given time and money. The mere fact that total syntheses still regularly make it into *Angewandte* and *JACS* (and not just because the author is KCN) should show that there is still interesting stuff to be developed. Each one of these syntheses does add something new of value, whether it is a most elegant transformation that can serve as a template or a novel set of conditions allowing broader substrate scopes.

Answer (score -5):

The closest thing to organic chemistry would now be the shape and sequencing of protiens and or DNA. That field is best left alone as it takes too much time to pay anyone to get any applicable results.
Advances in things like machine learning are promising to the unraveling of these complex structures. Humams are better at recognising the patterns hence the "fold it" game.